# Uncaught ydn.error.ArgumentException: require index "Account__c,PrimaryContact__c" not found in store "contactRole" store.js line 1284

Tags: indexeddb, ydn-db

I have the following:

ydbStorage = new ydn.db.Storage(dbName, schema);

```
/**
@param values - An array of keys . e.g. ['account1', 'city1']
@param index - An string of index value . e.g. 'account, city'
@description - Get records based on compound index. Remember that indexes are not created for boolean values
*/
var getRecordsOnCompoundIndex = function(store_name, index, values, success_callback, failure_callback) {
  console.log('Inside getRecordsOnCompoundIndex');
  if(!store_name || ! index || !values) {
      failure_callback();
  } else {
  var keyRange = ydn.db.KeyRange.only(values);
      ydbStorage.values(new ydn.db.IndexValueIterator(store_name, index, keyRange)).done(function(response) {
        if(!response){
            failure_callback();
        }else{
            success_callback(response);
        }
      });
  }
}

$scope.getAccountKeyContact = function() {
  var indexes = 'Account__c,PrimaryContact__c';
  var values = [accountId, "true"];
  ydbDatabase.getRecordsOnCompoundIndex('contactRole', indexes, values, function(records) {
    //console.log('KeyContact role is : ', records);

    ydbDatabase.getRecordOnId('contacts', records[0].Contact__c, function(record) {
      $scope.outlet.keyContact = record;
      $scope.outlet.keyContact.designation = records[0].Role__c;
      $scope.$apply();
    }, function() {
      console.log('Could not get KeyContact');
    });

  }, function() {
    console.log('Could not get contactRole Role');
  });
}
```

[image: contactRole indexedDB store]

I am getting the following error in spite of the compound index being present.

Uncaught ydn.error.ArgumentException: require index "Account__c,PrimaryContact__c" not found in store "contactRole"

Can't figure out what is wrong. Any suggestions. The error is with the line ydbDatabase.getRecordsOnCompoundIndex

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have compound index as [describe here](http://dev.yathit.com/ydn-db/doc/query/cmpidx.html). It should be something like:

```
var schema = {
store: [{
    name: 'contactRole',
    indexes: [{
      name: 'AccuntContact',
      keyPath: ['Account__c', 'PrimaryContact__c']
    }]
  }]
};
```